# Springboot query criteria : mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I have list of *filtered Id* as following:

```
filteredId=[5,44,221,34,111...]
```

and class `Device.java`:

```java
@NotBlank
private String applicationId;

// @NotBlank
private String deviceTypeId;

@NotBlank
private String uid;

@NotBlank
private String name;
private String userId;
private String nodeId;
private String externalId;
private String softwareReleaseId;
private boolean enabled = CoreConstant.DEFAULT_ENABLED;
private boolean nameOverridden = KronosConstants.NAME_OVERRIDDEN_DEFAULT;
private Map<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();

//Getter Setter
```

I want to fetch **all** *Device*s which have **deviceTypeId** equals ***filteredId***

I am doing something like this:

```java
Query query = new Query();

for (int i = 0; i < filteredId.size(); i++) {
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(filteredId.get(i)).is(device.getId()));
}

return this.MongoOperations.find(query, Device.class);
```

Can anyone help me with what changes I need?

Comment: Why are you not simply using a @Query annotation and use JPQL - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query . Would be easier to read and maintain. Also you could try out the "magic methods" in spring JPA repositories - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries.

Comment: I also thought the same way but I had requirements to do some changes in already existing code.

Comment: In this case you could still use the Criteria builder or maybe subqueries - see https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-criteria-api-in-expressions

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<Integer> filteredId = List.of(5,44,221,34,111);
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("deviceTypeId").in(filteredId);
return mongoOperations.find(Query.query(criteria), Device.class);
```